# Securely Mounting LCD Display to Pi

Tags: gpio, pi-2, touchscreen, case

I have decided to add a [4D Systems 2.4" HAT display](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DPi-24-HAT/) to my R-Pi2B, however before I start mashing down on it, I would like to ensure that it is securely fastened to the Pi. I have my Pi seated in a [Foundation Case](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76996/l/raspberry-pi-official-enclosure-from-the-raspberry-pi-foundation?ICID=rpimain-picase-ban) and would like to mount my touch screen onto the pi, inside the case. I can currently do that, however there is no real physical support of the display unit aside from the GPIO it is connected to.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to mount this display securely to prevent damaging the GPIO while using the touchscreen? I could probably rig something using a couple of screws from my junk drawer, but I would prefer a little more of a "professional", cleaner looking approach. Is there a specific mounting bracket or kit, either DIY or for sale, out there for this exact purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the mounting holes on the HAT line up with the mounting holes on the Pi. I'd just use nylon hex spacers cut to size and a couple of small screws to hold everything in place.

Comment: I will look into that, I might be able to make something work in that direction. There is a small problem with the mounting holes on the Pi itself. Where the Pi is seated in the case, there are little "nubs" that extend up off of the case and into the mounting holes. I could possible grind those down/off to free up the space in the hole if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: It's proving irritatingly difficult to find a good picture of the internal nubbins. In [this](https://www.pretzellogix.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/official-rpi-case-2.jpg) shot it looks like there are only two, next to the USB sockets, holding the board in place. Would that be right, or are there four?

Comment: The two you see in that image extend fully through the holes, the far two extend partially into the holes.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer. I can at least secure spacer to the LCD and cut it so that it sits flush with the Pi board. That will at least provide support when pressing down on the display, even if it doesn't securely attach it to the board. Thank you sir.